# DynamoDbClient.BatchGetItem with only partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Given a table like:

```
ForumPosts
postId                      commentId
========================================
POST::100                   COMMENT:1
POST::100                   COMMENT:2
POST::100                   COMMENT:3
POST::100                   COMMENT:4
POST::100                   COMMENT:5
POST::101                   COMMENT:1
POST::101                   COMMENT:2
POST::101                   COMMENT:3
POST::101                   COMMENT:4
POST::101                   COMMENT:5
```

Is it possible to perform a batchGet on just postId=100 that returns the 5 items, or I can only do that with Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Query. Batch get requires knowing the full primary key for each item. If there’s a reason you’re thinking you’d rather do a batch get, please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks @hunterhacker. I 99% knew the answer, but I needed the confirmation.

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer.